# Simple equation solving in Maxima

Tags: math, equation, solver, maxima

I'm very new to Maxima (downloaded it 30 minutes ago), but I need a quick solution for a problem, it's not complex, I suppose I just don't know which is the right command to use.

My code:

```
ji:[31,59,91,120,151];
FCZ: 950.00;
FC: 207.79;
eqn:lsum(
  (FC)/((1+CET)^(j/365))
  , j, ji)-FCZ=0;
```

This is what Maxima returns (I know the solving part is missing, but the equation looks ok)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U815N.png)

Any helo appreciated

Comment: I need to know the value of 'CET'

Answer (score 1):

Maxima has the `solve` function and some other functions to solve equations, but the kinds of equations that can be solved is fairly limited. I am guessing that you'll have to look for a numerical solution for this problem.

You can plot the expression as a function of CET:

```
(%i8) plot2d (lhs(eqn), [CET, 0.01, 0.99]);
```

`lhs` returns the left-hand side of something (such as an equation).

From that I see there is a single root around CET = 0.4. To get a more precise numerical approximation:

```
(%i9) find_root (eqn, CET, 0.01, 0.99);
(%o9)                   0.4405719229090962
```